# Does "mkview" keep a record of `fdm` and `formatoptions`? If so, how to refresh it?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am having trouble with the following script written in Vim (by Yichao Zhou (); source: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4021). The question breaks down to details related with `mkview` and `loadview` in Vim.

When having this plugin installed through Vundle, I cannot set `fdm` and `formatoptions` to be some new values. This plugin keeps restoring not only the previous views, but also the setting for `fdm` and `formatoptions`.

Upon examining the code (appended at the end), I don't think any thing fancy should have happened. The only function that was called eventually is `mkview` and `loadview`.

So, per code listed below, where is it writing the "views" to? I would like to go there and delete everything old, in hope of making this plugin back normal. (i.e. accommodating the new specification of `fdm` and `formatoptions`.)

Thank you.

```
if exists("g:loaded_restore_view")
    finish
endif
let g:loaded_restore_view = 1

if !exists("g:skipview_files")
    let g:skipview_files = []
endif

function! MakeViewCheck()
    if &l:diff | return 0 | endif
    if &buftype != '' | return 0 | endif
    if expand('%') =~ '\[.*\]' | return 0 | endif
    if empty(glob(expand('%:p'))) | return 0 | endif
    if &modifiable == 0 | return 0 | endif
    if len($TEMP) && expand('%:p:h') == $TEMP | return 0 | endif
    if len($TMP) && expand('%:p:h') == $TMP | return 0 | endif

    let file_name = expand('%:p')
    for ifiles in g:skipview_files
        if file_name =~ ifiles
            return 0
        endif
    endfor

    return 1
endfunction

augroup AutoView
    autocmd!
    " Autosave & Load Views.
    autocmd BufWritePre,BufWinLeave ?* if MakeViewCheck() | silent! mkview | endif
    autocmd BufWinEnter ?* if MakeViewCheck() | silent! loadview | endif
augroup END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:mkview` command uses the `'viewdir'` location by default; you can inspect the value via

```
:set viewdir?
```

The reason you cannot change the options is because the default of `'viewoptions'` contains `options`, which IMO is a bad default (unless you often switch such interactively, and do want the recorded). You can fix that by

```
:set viewoptions-=options
```

in your `~/.vimrc`. Of course, the currently stored views still contain it, so you do need to clean them, too.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Does setting the `viewoptions` in the way as I did in my answer work? I think "options" will be dropped if I assign the `viewoptions` of values deliberately.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ingo's suggestions and Yichao's help (the author of the plugin), the problem had been solved using the following steps:

1. In `_vimrc`, specify the setting for `viewoptions` as:

   `set viewoptions=cursor,folds,slash,unix`
2. Specify the `viewdir`, *without* any marker for strings (shall not have any quotes, either `"` or `'`). My `viewdir` has been specified as follows:

   `set viewdir=C:\Users\llinfeng\Onedrive\Vim-document\ViewFiles`

   Or, one may leave the viewdir as default.

Note that, when Vim is confused about the specification of `viewdir`, it will start saving some weirdly named files onto the same folder as the file that it is "making a view of". For example, upon editing `_vimrc` and exiting, such "view" file will be found in the same directory, named (for my case) as: `C=-=+vim=+_vimrc=`. This could only be solved when specifying the `viewdir` correctly.

For "refreshing" the stored views, simply deleting everything in the `viewdir` should do the job.